# program involving operators not working

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to make a simple program where the user inputs a mark between 1 and 100 and depending on what mark is entered a certain grade is displayed on a label. I started of with a smaller program where if the mark is between 0 and 100 the text OK is displayed but if it is greater than 100 then NOT OK is displayed.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Grade = InputBox("What was the mark of the student?")
    If 0 < Grade < 100 Then
        Label1.Text = "OK"
    ElseIf Grade > 100 Then
        Label1.Text = "NOT OK"
    End If
```

But at the moment even if I type in number over 100, OK is still displayed. How do I fix this?

Comment: I didn't know VB.Net can do 'If 0 < Grade < 100 Then'

Comment: Another victim of OPTION STRICT OFF.

Comment: whats your `InputBox()` ???

Comment: @SamuelAdam: What it actually does is two comparisons combined with typecasting. `0 < Grade` returns True or False. Then either True/False is cast to integer (resulting in 0/-1) or 100 is cast to Boolean and then the second `<` comparison (0/-1 < 100, or True/False < True) is executed that returns a boolean. Overall: Bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `If` like this:

```
If Grade > 0 And Grade <= 100 Then
    Label1.Text = "OK"
Else
    Label1.Text = "NOT OK"
End If
```

You can't use an expression like this: `0 < Grade < 100`

It is also better validate your user input:

```
Dim Grade As Integer = 0

Try
    Grade = CInt(InputBox("What was the mark of the student?"))
Catch ex As Exception
End Try
```

Comment: Just a note: Catching an exception in the dark for when you actually expect an error with Try Catch is not so good. How do you go on with the code? Better use `Integer.TryParse` on the string returned by the InputBox and react accordingly in the code.

Comment: In this case if Grade remains 0 then it is "NOT OK".

Answer (score 0):

The issue you have is the `0 < Grade < 100`

What is happening is the compiler thinks you mean this:`(0 < Grade) < 100`

You can't evaluate two numeric values in one expression like that. Note that you should switch *Option Strict On* which will not allow this line to compile.

What you want is something like this:

```
If 0 <= Grade AndAlso Grade <= 100 Then
```

I would really recommend you don't use an InputBox to prompt for numeric values within a range. Just create your own form with a NumericUpDown control set to Min=0 and Max=100 then you can guarantee that the user can only enter valid numeric values.

Comment: I somehow downvoted this answer by accident while on mobile and can't change it anymore. Please disregard one downvote. Sorry.